# service_account_credentials_json in spatie/laravel-analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, laravel-5.3

hi there i'm trying to get the google analytics in my project , i managed to show it on google analytics but i can't show it on my project's admin panel .
i have always get this error  :

```
ErrorException in AnalyticsServiceProvider.php line 53:
Undefined index: service_account_credentials_json
```

and that's my controller :

```
$analytics= Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(
            Period::create(Carbon::now()->subMonth(), Carbon::now())
        );

        dd($analytics);
```

but i don't know what's the error as i did every thing as in tutorials , can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the analytics credentials file. Check the readme for instructions.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#how-to-obtain-the-credentials-to-communicate-with-google-analytics

You then need to place the file in.

```
storage/app/analytics/service-account-credentials.json
```

Comment: thnx for reply but i already did all this , and i placed the file already but i don't know what about it ?

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions to the storage folders?

Comment: yes i did and placed the file in it's specified place

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file /config/laravel-analytics.php or /config/analytics.php (for most recent versions) is missing. Remember to publish this file using the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider"
```

You should also remember to verify if your file /storage/app/analytics/service-account-credentials.json exists. If it doesn't exist generate this file following the steps written on https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics.

Hope it helps you!  =)